Does every holomorphic map admit a stratified submersion?
Given a map (germ) $g:(\mathbb{C}^{n+k},0)\rightarrow (\mathbb{C}^k,0)$, are there stratifications that make it a stratified submersion?
By stratified submersion I mean a map that has stratifications in source and target that are Whitney regular and such that it is submersive on strata.
